# Why are I/O Completion Port Packets Queued in FIFO order if they may be dequeued in a different order?

Tags: iocp

Microsoft's documentation for [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> Please note that while the [completion] packets are queued in FIFO order they may be dequeued in a different order.

It is my understanding that a thread obtains a completion packet from a completion port by calling [GetQueuedCompletionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Why does the system queue packets to a completion port in a FIFO order if it does not guarantee packets will be retrieved in a FIFO order?

Comment: I don't understand what "first-in first-*out*" even means when the first one out isn't the first one in....

Comment: @Mehrdad Good to know I'm not the only one who is perplexed.

Comment: *maybe* it means that under simple circumstances, using a single thread, packets are probably FIFO, but different threading conditions may change the order. ie. "queued in FIFO" should have read "queued in insertion order". but the dequeue mechanism varies for different reasons

Comment: FIFO still means something even if it's not strict FIFO. it tells you there will be throughput of the buffer. unlike a LIFO stack, where there could be packets "stuck at the bottom".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement that you quoted is intended to make you aware that you need to do your own sequencing if sequencing is required between I/O completions on a single socket. You might need this if you issue multiple WSARecv calls on a single socket. When they complete the completions will go into the IOCP queue in FIFO order and this will be the order that the WSARecv calls were issued.

If you keep reading that document you will see this piece:

> Threads that block their execution on an I/O completion port are
>   released in last-in-first-out (LIFO) order, and the next completion
>   packet is pulled from the I/O completion port's FIFO queue for that
>   thread. This means that, when a completion packet is released to a
>   thread, the system releases the last (most recent) thread associated
>   with that port, passing it the completion information for the oldest
>   I/O completion.

Which shows that the completions are removed from the IOCP in FIFO order. The reason for the first note is that if you have multiple threads waiting on an IOCP then thread scheduling issues may mean that your code processes the completions in a different order to the order that they were retrieved from the IOCP.

Imagine you have 2 threads servicing an IOCP and a single TCP socket with 3 WSARecvs pending. Enough data comes in from the network to complete all three pending WSARecvs and so you end up with three completions in the IOCP; we'll call them A, B & C. These are in the order that the WSARecv calls were issued and so the data in the buffers A, B & C should be processed in order to maintain the sanity of the TCP stream.

The first of your IOCP threads will be given completion A. The second thread will be given completion B. Depending on your hardware (number of cores, etc) and the OS scheduler either thread 1 or thread 2 may get to run next or both may run at the same time. This may cause you problems in the above situation.

I personally get around this by adding a sequence number to every buffer when writing servers that can issue multiple WSARecvs on a single socket. The sequence number is incremented, inserted in the buffer and the WSARecv issued inside of the same lock so that the whole operation is atomic. When the completions occur I ensure either that only one thread processes buffers for a given socket (see [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2014/08/activatable-object.html)) or I use a 'sequenced buffer collection' which can ensure that the buffers are processed in the correct sequence (see [here](http://www.serverframework.com/handling-multiple-pending-socket-read-and-write-operations.html)).

Note also that to ensure correctness you need to lock around issuing WSARecv (and WSASend) calls on a given socket anyway (see [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2014/08/activatable-object.html))

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight, Len.  Your explanation and example, lead me to believe that IOCPs do, in fact, work the way I had expected it to work before I saw Microsoft's "[completion] packets are queued in FIFO order [and] may be dequeued in a different order." comment.  

If I understand correctly, the documentation would be accurate if it stated that "completion packets are ALWAYS queued and dequeued to/from a completion port in FIFO order." Standard threading behavior (scheduling, etc.) can affect the order in which threads can dequeue from a completion port"

Comment: That's my understanding of this and it's what my unit tests show when run with an IOCP which is only serviced by a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

1. first, make the buffer large enough to receive all data, if possible.
2. do NOT post receive by WSARecv multi times for one socket.
3. after connected, or after read data, process these date, then post WSARecv at last.

sum: only one receive buffer for one socket at any time.

I finish my IOCP server for server side, client side, file read, write, TCP & UDP for only ONE iocp handle.

Comment: I do a test years ago. Set the received buffer size to double of TCP slider windows size(which is 64k at most for TCPv4), get the best performance.